# Android Studio can't add image or vector resources

Tags: android, nativescript

I'm trying to use vector images in a NativeScript project on Android. I made a build, then loaded the project (under `platforms/android`) into Android Studio on Windows 10. When I right click on the project and select `New >`, the menu items `Add image asset` and `Add vector asset` are simply not there.

I know vector assets require at least Android SDK 21. I changed `app/build.gradle`:

`def minSdkVer = manifest."uses-sdk"."@android:minSdkVersion".text() ?: 21`

But it changed nothing, even after rebuilding the NativeScript project, and besides even if a low minimum SDK version is the issue, I should still be able to add images.

Right clicking on the `res` directory or any subdirectories doesn't help: the menu items never appear.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You are not suppose to modify anything under platforms folder, those are auto generated / compiled project. Do any of your changes with your {N} source. For vector images, you should load them in your App Resources, display with plugins. You may browse through all available plugins at https://market.nativescript.org/

Comment: That's not how it works.

Comment: Sorry what you mean by that. Are you looking for something else. I understood you wanted vector images in your app and that's how you do it. Please be more specific if you are looking for something else. But in any case you are not suppose to edit the platforms folder manually, you will loose the changes when you rebuild.

Comment: I managed to get this work once, but it was a year ago and on a Mac. I even wrote an article about the method. But now I'm stuck as the menu isn't there.